# substr check if 2 first chars is numeric not working

Tags: php

I have this, i followed PHP manual :

```
                      if(is_numeric(substr($username,0, 2))){
                         echo 'Invalid - use letters in first 2 chars';
                        }else{
                           echo 'Valid';
                        }
```

And i checked this strings:

- 9dddd = valid .
- 99ddd = Invalid .

Why its doing like this ?
Its should return Invalid for 9dddd too , what wrong here its looking good ?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Thanks you really , i used OlivierH sample already and working perfect.

**Solved.**

Comment: You prevent the username from beginning with 2 numerics, but if there is only one this is OK, "9d" is not numeric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you want to test if **2 first characters of the username contains a numeric**.
The best way to do it is to use a regex ([documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php))

Change this :

```
if(is_numeric(substr($username,0, 2))){
    echo 'Invalid - use letters in first 2 chars';
}
else{
    echo 'Valid';
}
```

To

```
if(preg_match('#[0-9]#', substr($username,0, 2))){
    echo 'Invalid - use letters in first 2 chars';
}
else{
    echo 'Valid';
}
```

Comment: Well , i did other way , but ur way is simple and working perfect , thanks you , i will accept in few minute, StackOVerflaw limit.

Answer (score 2):

You got the wrong order. You display "invalid" if the two signs ARE numbers.

Comment: this what i want , return false(invalid) if the 2 chars is numeric.. E.G: not allowed 9dddd, 99dddd . allow dddd , sdfsdf .

Comment: Well, you're checking if the 2 first chars are numeric. But if the two chars are 9d then 9d is not numeric, so it will display valid in your case.

Comment: OH , now i understand , so you have any idea ?

Comment: You can just try to check both signs. For example `if(is_numeric(substr($username,0, 1)) || is_numeric(substr($username,1, 1)))`

Comment: Yes , i got an solution too  my way, and your way working too , and in the end i will use OlivierH way, simplest way , thanks you allot.

Answer (score 0):

9d is not numeric, you must check this with regex :

```
if(preg_match('/\d/', substr($username,0, 2))){
    echo 'Invalid - use letters in first 2 chars';
}else{
   echo 'Valid';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that
substr($username,0, 2) in your case with 9aaa will return 9a .. 9a isn't a valid numeric.

You should do something like

```
if (is_numeric(substr($username,0, 1)) || is_numeric(substr($username,0, 2))){
   echo 'Invalid - use letters in first 2 chars';
} else {
    echo 'Valid';
}
```

in order to check both for single or double first chars.